# How to enable update option in SQL server 2008

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm working in ASP.NET ( beginner ) and I tried to make update query using the code below. I try the same code to get date from database and it work fine, but only don't work with update query.

Note:  I use LINQ

```
Dim updateCust = (From cust In db.Customers 
                  Where cust.CustomerID = "JILLF").ToList()(0)

updateCust.ContactName = "Jill Shrader"

Try
    db.SubmitChanges()
Catch
    ' Handle exception.
End Try

RefreshData()
```

I got this code  from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907191.aspx

Should I change something in my SQL server 2008 so I could use update option ?

Comment: Are there any exceptions? Try to rethrow error in your Catch. `Throw` or `Throw ex`

Comment: I try to use try and catch , but it look like it is success. Then I check it again and I found nothing is updating in my database.

Comment: Please check the logs on Sql Server Profiler and check what gets sent along the wire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting your results into a `List` and then take first element. You'll get the data but it is not bound to database any more. I believe something like this would work:

```
Dim updateCust = (From cust In db.Customers 
                  Where cust.CustomerID = "JILLF").FirstOrDefault()

If updateCust IsNot Nothing Then
    updateCust.ContactName = "Jill Shrader"
End If

db.SubmitChanges()
```

**EDIT**

Although `FirstOrDefault()` would work fine here you may want to use `SingleOrDefault()` which would throw an exception if there were more than one record with the same `CustomerID` (or broadly, more records returned). I assume that this column is a primary key column (it looks like it) and that guarantees row uniqueness.

Comment: Well, I have just run the code with both versions (`FirstOrDefault` and `ToList()(0)`) and they both work i.e. DB gets updated. `FirstOrDefault`/`SingleOrDefault` is preferred in my opinion. There must be another problem - are you sure your connection string is right? If you have it in project settings you should be able to test it by following ... button when editing Value column.